# How to solve for angles $4\theta = \theta$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to find all the angles in $[0, 2\pi)$ for which $4\theta = \theta$ is true. I can obviously get $\theta = 0$, but the other solutions are $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. How do I find these particular ones?

Comment: @graydad: He never claimed that those two angles are equal, but that each of them _individually_ satisfies $4\theta\equiv\theta \pmod{2\pi}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The $\pmod{2\pi}$ part got left out of the question. I wondered if the problem was it also got left out of the _thinking_ about the question, or whether the problem was dealing with the modulus.

Comment: @DavidK: My immediate interpretation of the question was that the OP understood _that_ $\frac{2\pi}3$ and $\frac{4\pi}3$ are solutions, but couldn't figure out how he would have _arrived_ at them systematically.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That too was certainly possible based on the problem statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two angles are "the same angle" when they differ by a multiple of $2\pi$. So you want to solve
$$ 4\theta = \theta+2k\pi$$
for all $k$. Solving this, we get
$$ \theta = \frac k3 2\pi $$
from which we see that solutions for $k$s that differ by a multiple of $3$ will be the same. So we get all solutions by taking the ones for $k=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the equations $$4\theta=\theta+2\pi$$ and $$4\theta=\theta+4\pi$$ to get the two other solutions you are after.  You could add $6\pi$ but the solution to that would fall outside your bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The writing $4\theta = \theta$ is not accurate. I assume that you are solving some equation that takes the form: $\cos(4\theta) = \cos(\theta)$ or $\sin(4\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ or possibly something else.

This boils down to finding the solution of $4\theta \equiv \theta \pmod {2\pi}$

$$4\theta \equiv \theta \pmod {2\pi} \iff \exists \ k \in \mathbb Z \ / \  3\theta = 2k\pi \iff \exists \ k \in \mathbb Z \ / \ \theta = \frac23k\pi$$

Thus, the solutions to this equation are the elements of $\{\frac23k\pi \ ; \ k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Then, look for those solutions which are in $[0,2\pi)$.